# How To Make Mouse Hover on NSControlSegment With Menu Items in Cocoa Mac os development?

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa

I want to have mouse hover on NSSegmentControl with menu items, I know i need to do something in this.

[image: Screen Shot]

```
- (void)mouseDown:(NSEvent *)event
{

}
```

please guide me , as i am noobs to mac os development.

Answer (score 1):

You need to activate mouseMove events. One way is by adding tracking rects:

```
- (void)updateTrackingAreas {
    [super updateTrackingAreas];
    [self addTrackingArea:[[NSTrackingArea alloc] initWithRect:self.frame options:NSTrackingActiveAlways | NSTrackingInVisibleRect | NSTrackingMouseEnteredAndExited | NSTrackingMouseMoved owner:self userInfo:nil]];
}

- (void)mouseEntered:(NSEvent *)theEvent {
    [self updateMenu];
}

- (void)mouseExited:(NSEvent *)theEvent {
    [self updateMenu];
}

- (void)mouseMoved:(NSEvent *)theEvent {
    [self updateMenu];
}
```

But the UI doesn’t look like a mac app. If it really needs to look like this, maybe you are better off building it in HTML and embed an WebKitView??

Comment: George, its a native mac os app, i cant use webkit here, where i need to write this code , do i need to subclass NSSegmnetControl and write this code there. And also tell me in InitWithRect do i need to provide nscontrolsegment frames .

Comment: UpdateMenu is a method that shows the popups below the current segment.

How you set up the segmented control has nothing to do with question. You can find plenty of answers on this site.